# How to pass objects of different classes, that aren't related with inheritance,to each other(java)?

Tags: java

I have a project in java , a hotel application,where two classes the class reservation and class room need to pass their objects in the other method.I have tried these but the compiler cannot recognise the objects and their properties:"****Let me edit this after rightfull requests"**:***In my assignment the matchdtoroom method it needs to take a room object as an argument and match with a d reference to it.dom is an room object that i create in main to make the method work.I know iam not right but after a lot of work i didn't find anything else.Also in matchdtoroom method i return d because when i declare return type null the compiler says illegal type of expression.Please suggest other answers.***In other words the reservation needs a reference to room objects and the 'room' class uses reservation object r in addreserve and the compiler said i can't recognise r or d or dom.**

```
public class reservation{
     static int kratisid;//reservation id
     //the customer gives his info for reservation of a room
     reservation(String name,int reserveid,int arrival,int dstay,int people,room d,boolean s)//dstay days of stay in specific room,d reference to room object
     {
          d=null;

          Random rand=new Random();
           reserveid=rand.nextInt(500)+100;//Random reservation id
          if(s==true)
          {
               System.out.println("Enter your name please");
               Scanner scanner1= new Scanner(System.in);
               onoma=scanner1.nextLine();
            }
            else {String alphabet= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";      
                   name = "";
                  Random random = new Random();
                  int randomLen = 1+random.nextInt(9);
                  for (int i = 0; i < randomLen; i++) {
                  char c = alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(26));
                   name+=c;     
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Enter your day of arrival please ,it must be from 1 to 30 max");
            Scanner scanner2=new Scanner(System.in);
             arrival=scanner2.nextInt();
            if(arrival<1 && arrival>30){
                arrival=0;
                System.out.println("Please re-enter your arrival within the month boundaries");
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of days you will be staying");
            Scanner scanner3=new Scanner(System.in);
             dstay=scanner3.nextInt();


        }
       room  matchdtoroom(room dom){ 
           room d=this.dom;
            return d;
        }
    }
```

the next class:

```
public class room  {
    static int roomid=100;
   reservation[] diathes=new reservation[30];//diathes[30] availability table with references to reservation objects
   static int maxpeople =4;

    Domatio(int roomid,int maxpeople,double priceindividual)
    {
        roomid++;
        maxpeople=4;
        for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
        {

        diathes[i]=null;
        }
         priceindividual=50.00;
    }

    boolean addreserve(reservation r,)//r reservation object
    {

        boolean k=false;
        for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
        {
            if(diathes[i]!=null || maxatoma>4)
            k=false;
            else// for( int z = arrival+1; z< arrival+dstay; z++)//give reservation objects in availability table for a room
            r=diathes[i];
            k=true;
        }
       r.matchdtoroom(this.Domatio);//here it doesen't recognise r
        return k;

    }
}
```

The object i have created in main but how in matchdtoroom and addreserve i pass objects reservation type and room accordigly so as to my compiler to recognise them and use them.Thanks in advance.

Comment: the constructor Domatio in second class is a mistake , i meant room() and some code is out of the code block ,sorry for the incovennience.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. you'll need to trim down the code and only show where the error is occurring. Also post the error log.

Comment: Edit your code to accurately reflect your attempt.

Comment: And please add the error messages from the compiler.

Comment: @Joe you can edit your post.

Comment: What do is `r.matchdtoroom(this.room)` suppose to be doing? Especially since `matchdtoroom` simply returns the argument passed to it...? EDIT: actually, it does nothing with the argument, and tries to access `this.dom`, but `reservation` doesn't have a `dom` attribute as far as I can tell...

Comment: thanks for your kind observations i will edit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the clases that are defined in another place to be recognized by the compiler.

import the "reservation" class in the file where you are defining your "room".

```
import yourPackage.reservation;//To be able to use reservation class on this file

public class room  {
static int roomid=100;
reservation[] diathes=new reservation[30];//diathes[30] availability table with references to reservation objects
static int maxpeople =4;

Domatio(int roomid,int maxpeople,double priceindividual)
{
    roomid++;
    maxpeople=4;
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {

    diathes[i]=null;
    }
     priceindividual=50.00;
}

boolean addreserve(reservation r,)//r reservation object
{

    boolean k=false;
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        if(diathes[i]!=null || maxatoma>4)
        k=false;
        else// for( int z = arrival+1; z< arrival+dstay; z++)//give reservation objects in availability table for a room
        r=diathes[i];
        k=true;
    }
   r.matchdtoroom(this.Domatio);//here it doesen't recognise r
    return k;

}
}
```

The same applies for every class you define, you need to import foreign references using the "import" clause above of everything.

And by the way, I recomend you to define your classes starting with Upper case following the CamelCase convention, like "Reservation" "Room" "SomeOtherClass" is a standard in the Java language.